# Android: can not write to a txt file

Tags: android, file

My program contains a file with the name "size.txt", which contains just a word "15". If a user choose a value from a spinner,say 17, then the chosen value should be stored in the file and replace "15".

I have added the permission to the program

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

But somehow i can not make the chosen value be written to the file. Here is my code

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("size", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    osw.write("17");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
//do something if an IOException occurs.
}
```

Can anybody help me? Thank youvery much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe you should read this, before looking for a way to fix your code.**

According to [Shared Preferences | Android Developer Tutorial (Part 13)](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) by Sai Geetha M N,

> Many applications may provide a way to capture user preferences on the
>   settings of a specific application or an activity. For supporting
>   this, Android provides a simple set of APIs.
>
> Preferences are typically name value pairs. They can be stored as
>   “Shared Preferences” across various activities in an application (note
>   currently it cannot be shared across processes). Or it can be
>   something that needs to be stored specific to an activity.

1. Shared Preferences: The shared preferences can be used by all the components (activities, services etc) off the applications.
2. Activity handled preferences: These preferences can only be used with in the activity and can not be used by other components of the application.

**Shared Preferences:**

The shared preferences are managed with the help of `getSharedPreferences` method of the `Context` class. The preferences are stored in a default file(1) or you can specify a file name(2) to be used to refer to the preferences.

(1) Here is how you get the instance when you specify the file name

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

`MODE_PRIVATE` is the operating mode for the preferences. It is the default mode and means the created file will be accessed by only the calling application.  Other two mode supported are `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. In `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` other application can read the created file but can not modify it. In case of `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` other applications also have write permissions for the created file.

(2) **The recommended way** is to use by the default mode, without specifying the file name

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Finally, once you have the preferences instance, here is how you can **retrieve the stored values** from the preferences:

```
 int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

To **store values** in the preference file `SharedPreference.Editor` object has to be used. `Editor` is the nested interface of the `SharedPreference` class.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

Editor also support methods like `remove()` and `clear()` to delete the preference value from the file.

**Activity Preferences:**

The shared preferences can be used by other application components. But if you do not need to share the preferences with other components and want to have activities private preferences. You can do that with the help of `getPreferences()` method of the activity. The `getPreference` method uses the `getSharedPreferences()` method with the name of the activity class for the preference file name.

Following is the code to get preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

The code to store values is also same as in case of shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

You can also use other methods like storing the activity state in database. Note Android  also contains a package called `android.preference`. The package defines classes to implement application preferences UI.

To see some more examples check Android's [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) post on developers site.

Comment: Instead of copy and pasting an answer from another question, you really should just link to it. I guess this is the one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317812/can-i-perform-database-specific-operation-using-android-preference-package 

...which again seems copy-n-pasted from this article: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: (1) When questions do not related each to other, I don't see the why I would link to them. The user just get confused when he checks the Linked area on the right column of the site. (2) From my experience a detailed answer is more valuable than a linkage to a site, which sometimes never gets read (3) An answer with a content link might not be rated as much as if someone else posts a more related answer. Just run a statistic on the SO site and see how many of the answers are accepted that has a linking vs. plain textual answers. The later wins.

Comment: This is really a good answer! I have not just solved my problem, but also learned how preference works and how to store very small data amount efficiently. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
*package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetFromURLActivity extends Activity 
{   
    TextView txtContent;
    String path;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            //this is the file you want to download from the remote server

            /*path ="http://localhost:82/TextureTest01.apk";*/
            path ="http://10.0.2.2:82/my.txt";
            //this is the name of the local file you will create

            /*String targetFileName = "mynew"; // Omit extension.
            boolean eof = false;*/
            URL u = new URL(path);

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();


            Log.e("value",in.toString());

            //Gets the instance of the asset manager
            AssetManager mngr=getAssets();

            //Resources resources = new Resources();
            //resources.getAssets().open("my.txt");
            //FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\" + targetFileName));

            /*FileOutputStream f = this.openFileOutput(targetFileName,
                    this.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);*/

            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); //  Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

            /*int len1 = 0;
            while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) 
            {
                //f.write(buffer,0, len1);
                bo.write(buffer,0, len1); // Write Into Buffer.
            }*/
            txtContent =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
            txtContent.setText(bo.toString()); 
            bo.close();
            //f.close();

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            //txtContent.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //txtContent.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //txtContent.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //txtContent.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
    String ReadFile(InputStream is)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte [] buffer=new byte[1024];

        try {
            is.read(buffer);
            bo.write(buffer);

            bo.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bo.toString();
    }
}
// My Email Id is muhammad.mubashir.bscs@gmail.com*
```