# Saving to File Android

Tags: android, file, file-io

Im having trouble debugging some code of mine. Its a simple note store app at the moment, that attempts to store a string to a file in the background. But when i run the app on my tablet I get the toast that confirms the code ran, but I cant find the file on my tablets internal storage to prove its been stored?

My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Gets the note detail from the fields.
            noteContent = content.getText().toString();
            noteTitle = title.getText().toString();
            Date date = new Date();

            if (noteContent.length() == 0 || noteTitle.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in both note title and content before saving",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

            //Adds the notes together as an object of note.
            note createdNote = new note(noteContent, noteTitle);
            //Adds the note to the object array.
            noteArray.add(createdNote);
            //Testing
            note test = noteArray.get(0);
            String testTitle = test.getTitle();
            String testContent = test.getContent();
            System.out.println(testTitle);
            System.out.println(testContent);
            //Concatenating string.
            String noteString = testTitle + "-" + testContent;


            try {
                FileOutputStream FO = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(FO);
                try {
                    System.out.println(noteString);
                    osw.write(noteString);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOTE_SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have also included the permissions to read/write :s

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using File Explorer of DDMS and browse to /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/files/ <- you can find your file.
Refer here for more options [Android: can not write to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326518/android-can-not-write-to-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the permissions since you are writing to internal memory. To the problem, why would you open the file like this: `FileOutputStream FO = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`?